# Build layers with fixed weights in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to build a fully-connected (dense) layer for a regression task. I usually do it with TF2, using Keras API like:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(1, )))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
model.fit(inp_data, out_data, epochs=1000)
```

Now I  want to build a custom layer. The layer is composed of, say 10 units, in which 8 units have predefined, fixed, untrainable weights and biases and 2 units have randomly-chosen weights and biases, to be trained by the network. Has anyone any idea how can I define it in Tensorflow?

Comment: There are many ways to do that, marking variables as not trainable, selecting the variables to train in the optimizer or simply using constants instead of variables, for example, but it depends on how you are building your neural networks (raw TF, `tf.layers`, Keras, ...). Also on whether you are using TF 1.x or 2.x. Please give more details in your question, and ideally a minimal example of how you would usually build a simple neural network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keras layers may receive a `trainable` parameter, `True` by default, to indicate whether you want them to be trained. Non-trainable layers will just keep the value they are given by the initializer. If I understand correctly, you want to have one layer which is only partially trainable. That is not possible as such with existing layers. Maybe you could do it with a custom layer class, but you can have an equivalent behavior by using two simple layers and then concatenating them (as long as your activation works element-wise, and even it it doesn't, like in a softmax layer, you could apply that activation after the concatenation). This is how it could work:

```py
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
# This is the trainable part of the layer
layer_train = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
# This is the non-trainable part
layer_const = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='sigmoid', trainable=False)(inputs)
# Merge both parts
layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([layer_train, layer_const])
# Make model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layer)
# ...
```